# Origin of the name "Carinio"

Tags: etymology

I was speaking with a friend recently, and I remarked on how odd it was that most people do not know the meaning and/or etymology of their own name even though they are called by it every single day.

She mentioned she had a horse named "Carinio" (apparently it used to be a famous race horse, I believe). I thought it sounded Italian, but I have had zero luck in finding *any* references concerning the name "Carinio" for a horse or otherwise (the only thing I managed to find was a reference to Carino's Italian restaurant).

Does anyone have a reference for such a name (or can point me to a proper place to look for references)?

Comment: Could you possibly mean: ***Cariño***  which might be considered a homophone?

Comment: @Jim I saw that word in my search and it seemed plausible, but I don't think that's it. Could be though.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain? I'm new to ELU.SE but not SE as a whole. Did I infringe on a community standard? If someone just deems it an uninteresting question, then I can live with that, but I respect the community rules and want to abide by them.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow If I had to guess about the DV: Names are often considered to be separate from the language. They're not found in most etymological resources, and there may well be no definite answer to this question. If I had to guess about the horse though, a quick google search brings up [this page](http://www.thenational.ae/sport/horse-racing/al-shamsi-misses-out-on-top-spot), which talks about a horse called "Carinio 7", although it doesn't seem to be a famous racehorse by any definition.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it's not hard to imagine that origins of surnames is not going to focus on the English language.  SE has its own board for this--https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/--which should be more responsive.  Enjoy.

Comment: I don't see how this could be anything *but* cariño.

Comment: Not only is it _not cariño_, but I found multiple references to as many as 9 thoroughbreds with the name. One seems to be named Don Carinio --[as seen on this pedigree (mother)](http://www.pedigreequery.com/don+carinio)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the English Languague.

Comment: There is a champion dressage (not racing) horse called [Carinho des Noes](http://www.allbreedpedigree.com/carinho+des+noes). "Carinho" is the Portuguese equivalent of the Spanish "Cariño".

Answer (score 1):

I speak Spanish as a second language.  Cariño - pronounced (kareenyo) refers to the child like sentiment of love toward say a teddy bear.  There is no English equivalent.  I looked the word up in my Spanish dictionary and it says - affection, fondness, tenderness, kindness. 
I looked in (http://spanishetym.com/directory/c?page=6) for root meanings.  One lead says  "Roberts (2014) believes the source was from cariñar "to miss," a word endemic to Aragon. Alternatively, the word may come from Aragonese cariño 'id.' Both proposed etymologies likely come from Latin carere "to lack" (see carecer a word which directly derives from this verb)."
Since in Spanish cariño has the masculine "o" ending - I thought it odd since words associated with intimacy are linguistically a more feminine trait in Spanish.  I would expect the word to end in "a".

Perhaps this word is associated with "caress" in English.  Chambers Etymological Dictionary points to (Italian) carezza - endearment, (Latin) carus - dear [see charity]

Comment: You write that *cariño* is pronounced "kareenyo" but in Spanish it would be pronounced [kaˈɾiɲo] not [kʰəˈɻʷinjoʊ̯] as it would be in English. There are quite a few differences there with almost every phoneme being differently realized phonetically.

Comment: 'Cariño' in Spanish (pronounced 'kareenyo' in English) is used as an affectionate appellation in rhe same way as ''Dear' , 'Darling', 'Honey', 'Love' etc in English.

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look at the town of Cariño in Galicia you will note its kidney like shape.  The word would seem to mean 'affectionate'.
go to wales you will see Ca'er/cadair at the beginning of placenames.  In Ireland you will find caher. it means seat or chair from cathaoir.  There is always a fort near by like cahersiveen for example. Riño means kidney.  originally it may have been caer-riño.  high seat shaped like a kidney.

Qatar
cathar
catherginians

[image: Aerial view of town of Cariino]

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carinatae